# Keeping live update coming from WMS using PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, wms, update

I'm using a WMS that contain weather radars that is update every 10 min.
I would like to know how to keep the map updating every 10min.

I tried:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
timer = QTimer()
timer.setInterval(600000)
QObject.connect(timer, SIGNAL("timeout()"), qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().refresh) 
timer.start()
```

but my WMS doesnt update.

Comment: When i'm using the "refresh buttton" everything refresh. What would be the code for doing the same thing? Obviously i would prefer to refresh only the WMS source.

Answer (score 3):

It's likely caused by the fact that the canvas renders a cached image instead of requesting a new one.

This will cause the cache to be cleared.

```
timer.timeout.connect(layer.triggerRepaint)
```

To get a reference to your layer either create it from python or use the QgsMapLayerRegistry.

Comment: I'm really new to this. I tried "timer.timeout.connect(layer.triggerRepaint)", but not sure how to. and for the reference, i don't know how to use "QgsMapLayerRegistry". My goal is to refresh one raster layer coming from a WMS.

Comment: What about this : With WMS raster layers, these commands do not work. In this case, you have to do it explicitly


layer.dataProvider().reloadData()
layer.triggerRepaint()